# How to make elasticsearch work with phrases?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say we have a query string "This is a test string"

Is it possible to write a query so it will find "It's a string for the test indeed"?

I tried fuzziness (and it didn't work of course). Also tried splitting the phrase by word and writing an OR condition for each word but also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with Match query. You can give more details of your query?

```
POST your_index/_doc
{
  "message":"It's a string for the test indeed"
}

GET your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "This is a test string"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Match phrase query` which looks for particular sequence of terms in field:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "field_name": "It's a string for the test indeed"
    }
  }
}
```